# Compatibility of two definitions of elliptic elements in GLn

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, reductive-groups

For an element $g$ of a connected reductive group $G$ (over a local field),

$g$ is called $elliptic$ if it is semisimple and the maximal split subtorus of the center of the centralizer of $g$ is equal to the maximal split subtorus of the center of $G$.

On the other hand, if $G$ is the general linear group $GL_{n}$, the notion of elliptic elements is defined as follows:

an element of $GL_{n}$ is $elliptic$ if its minimal polynomial is irreducible.

My question: are the above definitions compatible? If so, how can one prove it?
Or, is there a reference for the proof?

Please give me any advice.

## Later

This post included a question on regular elements, but
I could prove the compatibility of definitions of "regular elements" by using general eigenspace decomposition and explicit calculation.
So I omitted the question concerning regular elements.

Comment: Does it matter if the field is local or not?  Maybe that's relevant for "elliptic", where the condition that a polynomial be irreducible involves a ground field.   Concerning "regular", the definitions are certainly equivalent.  I think this was observed (for special linear groups, which is good enough here) by Steinberg in his IHES paper on regular elements.

Comment: P.S. An explicit sttement about regular elements is given in Steinberg's 1974 *Conjugacy Classes in Algebraic Groups* (Springer Lecture Notes 366, notes by V. Deodhar): see Prop. 2(c) on pages 95-96.  But he leaves the (elementary) proof as an exercise for the reader.  None of this is sensitive to the nature of the ground field.

Comment: Thank you for references! Do you know anything about elliptic elements?

Answer (score 3):

This is linear algebra. Let me put some notation: $K$ any field, $V$ a $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$, $u\in \mathrm{GL}_K(V)$.

Suppose the minimal polynomial $P_{min}$ of $u$ is irreducible; put $L:=K[x]/(P_{min})$. This is a finite extension of $K$, and we can view $V$ as a $L$-vector space. The centralizer of $u$ in $\mathrm{GL}_{K}(V)$ is $\mathrm{GL}_{L}(V)$, its center is $L^*$. The maximal split subtorus is $K^*$, that is, the center of  $\mathrm{GL}_{K}(V)$.

Conversely, if the minimal polynomial splits, we can write $V=V_1\times  V_2$ where  $V_1$ and $V_2$ are nonzero and stable under $u$. Then your center contains $K^*\times K^*$ acting by homotheties on $V_1\times V_2$.

Comment: The definitions of "elliptic" as given in the question are not compatible when $K$ is not perfect because ${\rm{R}}_{L/K}({\rm{GL}}_1)$ is not a $K$-torus when $L$ is not separable over $K$ (so a separability condition has to be manually inserted into a GL$_n$-specific description). More specifically, in the notation used in the answer, $u$ is not semisimple as a point of the algebraic group ${\rm{GL}}(V)$ if $P_{\rm{min}}$ is irreducible but not separable. (In linear algebra, semisimplicity of an endomorphism can be lost by an inseparable ground field extension.)

Comment: I think the OP was assuming characteristic 0 -- my answer certainly does